# How to use custom fields in post title?

Tags: custom-field

Certain posts of mine will have the custom field `release_author` in them - others don't.  If that field exists, I want to display that in the header.php's title (not in the `h1` of the post itself.

Right now this is the PHP that displays my title from the header.php file:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

So right now this is what it would display:

```
Random Title Name
```

This is what I want it to display:

```
Random Title Name (Author Name)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  I found a ton of tutorials similar to it, but they are all for modifying the title on the page itself, not for altering what shows up in the header...

Comment: Do you use `add_theme_support('title-tag')` or hardcode it?

Comment: @Dan It's hardcoded at the moment - the title tag is the code snippet above :) I've added an answer to convert it to the new way of doing things, though.

Comment: How did you go with this, user92726?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for are the filters that let you modify the page title. There is a new way of doing this since Wordpress 4.4, so I'm going to focus on that. If you happen to be using a version prior to 4.4 and you can't update, the alternative is the `wp_title` filter (not to be confused with the `wp_title()` function), which I can elaborate on if you'd like.

So, the filter you are after (for WP 4.4+) is called `document_title_parts`.

To use this, you want to open your theme's `functions.php` file and place in the following:

```
add_filter("document_title_parts", "wpse_224340_document_title");

function wpse_224340_document_title($title){
    global $post; // make sure the post object is available to us
    if(is_singular()){ // check we're on a single post
        $release_author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "release_author", true);
        if($release_author != ""){ $title["title"].= " (" . $release_author. ")"; }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

You'll also need to remove that `<title></title>` tag that you found in your `header.php`, and add the following code to your `functions.php` as well:

```
add_filter("after_setup_theme", function(){ add_theme_support("title-tag"); });
```

This is telling Wordpress that it's safe to add its own `<title>` tag, which you're then modifying with the `document_title_parts` filter above.

**EDIT:** As this is a fairly new change to Wordpress, if you're interested in the background behind it or you want to know why it's best not to use `wp_title` anymore, you can see [this blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/20/document-title-in-4-4/).

Comment: It will add blank `()` to every title. You should also check `is_singular()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Sumit - I've edited the post :) Feel free to add any other enhancements you have.

Comment: Haha oops, thx for that syntax error fix too @Sumit!