# How to add a theme custom variable to a post title?

Tags: custom-field, title

I'm trying to add a custom field to a post title ([sample page](https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/properties/hs0525-chaweng-noi-4-bedroom-coastal-front-villa/)).  To do so, I'm following the instructions given in [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224340/how-to-use-custom-fields-in-post-title), but the variable is not appearing in the title as expected.  In fact, the exact same title appears.  Any help would be appreciated.

The previous instructions indicate that the following code should be added to functions.php:

```
function wpse_224340_document_title($title){
    global $post; // make sure the post object is available to us
    if(is_singular()){ // check we're on a single post
      $release_author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "release_author", true);
      if($release_author != "")
        { $title["title"].= " (" . $release_author. ")";}
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter("after_setup_theme", function(){ add_theme_support("title-tag"); });
```

The variable in my case is *propertysq*, not *release_author*.  But a simple find/replace resulted in the following...

**What occurs when I implement this code?**

The current page title is: `HS0525 - Chaweng Noi - Horizon Homes Koh Samui`  This title has been inserted automatically by a Wordpress plugin "Yoast SEO."  But after I disable this automatic title insertion, and insert the above code, the title inserted onto the page is identical to the previous page title: `HS0525 - Chaweng Noi - Horizon Homes Koh Samui`

**Possible Sources of Error**

*Possible Source of Error #1*:  The aforementioned plugin/mechanism that is forcing its own `<title>` onto the page.  I am currently researching if this is the cause.  I'd like to avoid completely removing the plugin, but I may have to.

*Possible Source of Error #2*:  Would I need to edit the following line to correspond to my theme/functions?

```
$release_author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "release_author", true);
```

I tried replacing it with the following line, but it did not work.

```
$propertysq = ale_get_meta('propertysq');
```

---

I should note:

- This site does not have a proper test environment setup where I can easily see PHP errors and dump vars.
- Per the previous answer, I also remembered to comment out the `<title>` tag in my header.php.

  ---

edit:  Here is the exact code I've inserted into functions.php:

```
add_filter("document_title_parts", "wpse_224340_document_title");
function wpse_224340_document_title($title){
    global $post; // make sure the post object is available to us
    if(is_singular()){ // check we're on a single post
      $propertysq = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "propertysq", true);
      if($propertysq != "")
        { $title["title"].= " (" . $propertysq. ")";}
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter("after_setup_theme", function(){ add_theme_support("title-tag"); });
```

Comment: What is `ale_get_meta()`? I don't think this is a WordPress function - is it a custom function you've defined somewhere? Can you also edit in the exact code you've used, rather than just the code from the linked answer? I am of course assuming you've replaced every instance of `release_author`, but it would be better to see the exact code you have in case there's anything there causing an issue. Finally, it's very hard to develop without a test environment - can you set one up? Or temporarily put this site into debug mode?

Comment: Also, to make sure the meta key is actually there, can you try echo'ing it out? Or try adding some random text to the title to see if that is working. Basically, you want to try to isolate the issue to work out exactly what is causing it - whether it's the post, the custom field, the title tag.. etc.

Comment: @TimMalone.  ale_get_meta() is indeed a custom function defined by the theme.  I tried it because, as a diagnostic, if I change my <title> tag to:  <title><?php echo esc_attr(ale_get_meta('propertysq')); ?></title>, the value of propertysq is inserted as the page title, as expected.  I think this also suffices for your suggestion on echoing out the meta key?  Also, I added my exact code to my original question.

Comment: @TimMalone And with regards to a test environment, I agree that we should have one.  You're preaching to the choir. Unfortunately I've inherited this site though, so right now there is no budget for that.  After this (hopefully) small edit though, I will research what exactly it would entail with a site like ours and broach it with management.

Comment: @TimMalone, in trying to isolate, I've ascertained that *something* is re-adding a <title>, even after I remove the <title> code from header.php.  Furthermore, this mysteriously re-added <title> Is identical to the <title> I remove from header.php, which is:  <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>  I would say that <title> is set by the Yoast SEO plugin, but in the plugin settings, I've cleared the field that defines these page titles.Ive ascertained that the functions.php code is responsible for re-adding the identical <title>.So I think Im defining $propertysq incorrectly.

Comment: I have no idea about Yoast, but I know it does do things to the title. You'll probably need to disable it to help debug this - and if it is causing problems then that would be a support question for the Yoast forums. Having said that, thanks for adding your code, you need to change release_author to propertysq - it's not working at present because release_author is no longer defined.

Comment: Oh also - you're missing the first add_filter call from the original answer.

Comment: @TimMalone, ugh, sorry about those two. I can tell you that they were not present in my original test--those errors only surfaced in my haste to recreate the code I had added, then removed.  I know so because the first add_filter line brought my site down, because I forgot the first "a," resulting in "dd_filter()" being added to functions.php.  (what were you saying about that test environment? :-D) Anyway, for posterity, I *will* make those edits and attempt to implement them again properly.  It will take a few hours though.  When I do so, I'll report back here.

Comment: @TimMalone, and yes, the Yoast plugin does indeed do a lot with the title.  Last week I posted to the Yoast forums asking how to completely disable its automatic page titling, but received nothing :-/  Of course I want to disable it as a diagnostic test, but now many others in the company have grown to use and rely on it, so temporarily disabling it will require a bit of research and coordination.

Comment: @TimMalone OK I made your edits and gave it a shot.  But something is still adding a <title> identical to the <title> I commented out.  I'm going to step back and first try to disable the Yoast Plugin to see if that doesn't help.  Now, if I disable Yoast and *still* encounter the same issue, how might I go about isolating further?  Should I post back here?  It would be weird to start a new question.  Conversely, the Stack Exchange UI on my end is imploring me to avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: @TimMalone I was able to make some progress.  I disabled the Yoast SEO plugin to see if it was controlling page the <title>.  Sure enough, when I did so, then commented out <title> in header.php, the page title reverted to the page URL.  When I previously commented out <title>, the Yoast SEO plugin would continue to insert its own title.  But I'm not out of the woods yet.  When I then tried to insert your code into functions.php (see my original post for that snippet), the page title did not change--it remained the page URL.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you also added the second code block from the other answer, the one with after_setup_theme in it? And, are you using WordPress 4.4 or later?

Comment: @TimMalone I'm using WordPres 4.6.1.  And yes I did include the second code block.  I've edited my original question so it now shows the full code I included.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to use `propertysq` custom field/post meta in the title and you use Yoast SEO. ( Correct me if I'm wrong )

So, use this is your `functions.php`

```
function wpse239252_hook_title($title) {
global $post; // make sure the post object is available to us
if(is_singular()){ // check we're on a single post
  $propertysq = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "propertysq", true);
  if($propertysq != "") { //check if not empty
    $title = $propertysq.' - '.$title;
  }
}
return $title;
}

add_filter('wpseo_title', 'wpse239252_hook_title', 15, 1);
```

This will add `propertysq` field to your title as `1,002Sq Mt - HS0525 - Chaweng Noi - Horizon Homes Koh Samui` in your given example, where `propertysq = 1,002Sq Mt`.

P.S: To get post_meta propertysq, use `$propertysq = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "propertysq", true);`

Let me if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that @hkchakladar.  I tried it out--I inserted that code into functions.php, then commented out the <title> tag in header.php, but it did not work.  The page title did not change when I added the code to functions.php.  The page title *did* change when I commented out <title> in header.php, but it changed to the URL of the page.  In my original question, I was trying to insert *only* the propertysq field into the title as a diagnostic test.  Once I figure out how to do that, I'll insert additional fields and text into the title.  Cheers!

Comment: Is your Yoast SEO plugin active ? It works when seo plugin is active. Also can you share your header php part where you commented out `title` tag

Comment: Yes, the Yoast SEO plugin is active.  My immediate task is to disable it, then continue troubleshooting.  But that will require time.  I'll post back here when I've done so.  In the meantime, here is the <title> code  I commented out in header.php:  <!-- <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title> -->

Comment: I'm now able to temporarily disable the Yoast SEO plugin, just for testing purposes.  The code you suggested will concatenate the current title with the $propertysq value.  For testing purposes though, how would I simply replace the title with the $propertysq value?  Would it be $title = $propertysq;

Comment: Yes its is concatenated with current title with meta value. I think you wanted to do this. And to replace, you are correct, use `$title = $propertysq;`

Comment: I just got around to testing the code.  I commented out the <title> tag in header.php, then added your code, but the page title did not render as the $propertysq value as expected--it rendered as the page URL.  Thoughts?

I should note that the page titles renders as the URL whether I disable the Yoast SEO plugin or not.

Comment: Don't comment out the `<title>` tag. Activate the SEO plugin and then see.

Comment: OK I did not comment out <title>, and I activated the SEO plugin.  The page title rendered as something seemingly defined by the SEO plugin.  The exact page title was:  "Koh Samui Real Estate - HS0525 - Chaweng Noi - Horizon Homes Samui"  The $propertysq field does not appear in that title.

Answer (score 1):

Because so many people want to manipulate it, it is no longer fashionable to include `<title>` tags in your header. In stead you put `wp_head` there and allow manipulation of the title by supporting it in your theme:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','wpse239252_theme_init');
  function wpse239252_theme_init () {   
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    }
```

Now, all kinds of (SEO) plugins may want to work with that, using the [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) filter. If you do something using this filter and a plugin kicks in later, everything you have done may be lost. Now, I don't know which plugins you have installed, but you can make sure your filter is last by giving it a high priority, like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse239252_title_filter', 9999, 2 );
  function wpse239252_title_filter ($title,$separator) {
    ... do stuff with $title ...
    return $title;
    }
```

Comment: Before I try any more code, I'm going to first disable my SEO plugin (Yoast SEO) to see if I can further isolate the issue.  As you said, signs are pointing to *something else* manipulating <title> despite my best efforts.  Disabling the plugin though will require some time and coordination first.  I'll post my results back here.